# Is there a way to take panoramic pictures on Windows Phone?

Tags: apps, camera

I've seen the panoramic photos in iOS 6 and my Nexus S can take panoramic pictures as well.  Are there any Windows Phone devices that can do panoramic photos or maybe an app that can stitch multiple photos together for the same effect?

If not for WP7, is this something that was announced for WP8?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Nokia Lumia device then you can go for the **Camera Extras** app developed by Nokia itself. I have installed it and works very well with some other features too.

Comment: Yes I just downloaded this app...it also contains the group photo feature that works like the commercial from iPhone.

Comment: It also works on the Lumia 610 unlike PhotoSynth.