# Is there a way to shot panoramic photos like iOS on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, camera

I wanted to take some panorama pictures, so I tried the [Lumia Panorama](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/lumia-panorama/9wzdncrfhx4s) App, the best App for this task on Windows Phone (as far as I know).

The problem is that it is quite slow and cumbersome to use: you have to take several different photos in order to make a panorama, each photo takes some time to be shot (at least on my Lumia 830) and, worst of all, you have to **slowly** move the phone to the next predefined position! It is very easy to miss the target and you have to move back the phone and try again to reach the circle :-\

It seems easy and natural to do in this screenshot, but in reality is non-practical nor fast at all! 
Basically it is the same kind of "images superimposing" I was using 7 years ago on my iPhone 3G.

[image]

Is there a way to take panorama shots like you do on iOS? It's very natural (I tried), you just have to move the phone following a line, like this:

[image]

I really hope this will improve on Windows 10 mobile, but as far as I know, this is not among the [upcoming announced features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_Mobile#Version_history).

P.S.: Before asking I searched for already existing questions; I found [this one](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/is-there-a-way-to-take-panoramic-pictures-on-windows-phone/), but it's more general - I'm asking for a *specific way* to take panorama shots, not just taking panorama pictures - and outdated (the answers suggest Apps that are not even on the Store anymore).

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft recently (in July 2016) added this functionality to the Windows Camera app. It works the same way as in iOS - you hold the phone (or tablet, since Camera is a UWP app) vertically and slowly rotate it to the right.

The feature should be available as an app update (version 2016.715.21.0) to all devices running Windows 10 Mobile, and shows up as an additional button at the bottom, next to the still photo and camera mode buttons.

[image]

For more information, see the following links:

- [Windows 10 Camera gets Panorama mode with latest Fast Ring update. How To & Tips](http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/panorama-windows-10-mobile-camera)
- [Panorama arrives on Windows 10 Mobile with an update for Windows Camera](http://www.winbeta.org/news/panorama-arrives-windows-10-mobile-update-windows-camera)
- [Panorama mode comes to all Windows 10 Mobile users](http://mspoweruser.com/panorama-mode-comes-to-all-windows-10-mobile-users)

Comment: It is not available to all devices as the articles are stating. I don't have it on my Lumia 430. Seeing the comment in the mspoweruser article in your answer it is clear that this is not available to phone like Lumia 535, 532, 540, 430, 435, etc... despite the camera app version numbers are same. It seems that MS has not released the feature for certain low end models.